# Selecting columns from a pandas dataframe based on columns conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to select to new dataframe, columns that have 'C' in  value

```
protein 1   2   3   4   5
prot1   C   M   D   F   A
prot2   C   D   A   M   A 
prot3   C   C   D   F   A
prot4   S   D   F   C   L
prot5   S   D   A   I   L
```

So i want to have this:

```
protein 1   2   4   
prot1   C   M   F   
prot2   C   D   M    
prot3   C   C   F   
prot4   S   D   C   
prot5   S   D   I
```

Number of colums can be n, i found examples only which i must specify column name... i cant do this here. The script should check column by colummn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
np.random.seed(123)
n = np.random.choice(['C','M','D', '-'], size=(3,10))
n[:,0] = ['a','b','w']
foo = pd.DataFrame(n) 
print (foo)
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  a  M  D  D  C  D  D  M  -  D
1  b  M  D  M  C  M  D  -  M  C
2  w  C  -  M  -  D  M  C  C  C

mask = foo.eq('C').any()
#set columns which need in output
mask.loc[0] = True

#filter
print (foo.loc[:,mask])
   0  1  4  7  8  9
0  a  M  C  M  -  D
1  b  M  C  -  M  C
2  w  C  -  C  C  C
```

Comment: It's cool but theres no protein column and somethimes columns not load all values :(

Comment: So need compare only columns which numbers? Al is possible set columns which are always in output?

Comment: https://scontent-frt3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t35.0-12/18110337_10207220766232360_1526389025_o.png?oh=7dfbf95e92fb78c6f64ace2728de378e&oe=58FDAAB0 dont know if links works

Comment: and yes :) proteins + 1..n

Comment: Thank you for link. I think main question is how add columns which are always in output, if no `C` in them. My edit solution works if all columns are numeric, then `cols2` return empty list.

Comment: And also add all not numeric columns to output like `protein`, 'col'...

Comment: If no C in them then this columns are omitted

Comment: wait, `protein` is index or column? what is `print (df.index)` ?

Comment: First column are the names of proteins, and all other is aminoacids (str) or '-'

Comment: print (df.index)
Index(['>Fungi|A0A0TG4.1/69-603 0061-domain-containing protein {ECO:00013|EMBL:E9955.1}',
       '>Fungi|G3ZV4.1/55-605 Uncharacterized protein {ECO:0013|EMBL:E24375.1}',
       '>Fungi|G7X4.1/49-584 U domain protein {ECO:0313|EMBL:GAA85617.1}'...

Comment: hmmm, so in output need `protein` column also if no `C` in them? And sometimes `protein` column is missing? If yes, second solution works perfectly.

Comment: and no problem if some columns have no values, it works nice too.

Comment: Need :
protein 11 22  234 324
prot1     C   A   C    D
prot2      A  C    D    C
prot3      C   A   D     F

protein name + column where C occurred at least once


sory dont know hp=ow to edit comment xD

Comment: Ok i will check your sollution :)

Comment: can you chceck what im doing wrong?/

foo = pd.DataFrame(n)
foo = foo.rename(columns = {0: 'protein'})

df = foo.set_index('protein')
new = df.loc[:,mask]


canj you check whats wrong?


cols2 = df.columns[~df.columns.str.isdigit()]
mask = df.eq('C').any()
mask.loc[cols2] = True
new = df.loc[:,mask]

Comment: What is `n`? some data?

Comment: yess. ok i got it :) just     
foo = pd.DataFrame(n)
foo = foo.rename(columns = {0: 'protein'})


new = foo[['protein']].join(foo[foo.columns[foo.eq('C').any()]])

Comment: Hmmm, but my solution works also. Or something problem? `foo = pd.DataFrame(n) foo = foo.rename(columns = {0: 'protein'})`

Answer (score 2):

```
In [22]: df[['protein']].join(df[df.columns[df.eq('C').any()]])
Out[22]:
  protein  1  2  4
0   prot1  C  M  F
1   prot2  C  D  M
2   prot3  C  C  F
3   prot4  S  D  C
4   prot5  S  D  I
```